# Busboy Content-Type header is present but still getting an error saying missing Content-Type

Tags: arrays, busboy, netlify-function

I am using netlify functions to make an API. When the user submits multipart/form-data, I need to parse that data using busboy.

But when I do this:

```
const busboy = new Busboy({headers: event.headers})
```

I get an error saying missing content type. But if I console.log event.headers, `content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=......` is present.

What should I do to fix it.
I am using `netlify-lambda serve` to serve the functions locally

Comment: Follow this -> https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/07/29/how-to-process-multipart-form-data-with-a-netlify-function/

Comment: Is pdf file content working for you?